# C#: Get all week numbers from within 2 dates globalized/ISO 8601 compatible

Tags: c#, date, numbers

I have a

*startdate* **2010-01-01** (I just assume its a first day of the week)

and an

*enddate* **2010-07-31** (I just assume its a first day of the week)

I want to have returned from a method all week numbers for every first day of the week for the

above timespan. I can not assume that the first day of week is always monday, because my user

could be from **Sweden**, **USA** or whereever. The algorythm should be compatible with ISO 8601.

The final result should look roughly like this:

```
2010-01-01 , 1
2010-01-08 , 2
2010-01-15 , 3
2010-01-22 , 4
...
2010-07-31 , ~28
```

Yes I know google is full of links about that topic but nobody is doing it right. They all

assume that monday is first day of a week. Maybe some of the c# gods on SO pass by :P

EDIT:

What do you say to this code:

```
public static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime dtPassed)
        {
            CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtPassed, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
            return weekNum;
        }
```

I found it partly on google and changed it a bit.

Comment: That's more or less where I was going with my answer.  You beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear

Edit:

Small fix for your own example, plus making it an extension so it's easier to use ;)

```
public static int GetWeekNumber(this DateTime dtPassed)
{
    CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    DateTimeFormatInfo fiCurr = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtPassed, fiCurr.CalendarWeekRule, fiCurr.FirstDayOfWeek);
    return weekNum;
}
```

the this infront of DateTime allows you to use it as if it's a function for a DateTime object..

so you could do

```
int week = DateTime.Now.GetWeekNumber();
```

Comment: You also may want to use DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CalendarWeekRule for the rule since some countries like mine (dutch) use the FirstFourDayWeek rule.

Comment: but I thought the First4DayWeek rule is not compatible with iso 8601 ? As I said I want to consider .nl , .se etc... all of them :)

Comment: @Doggett I found this quote on google:"... One point about culture dependence is DayOfWeek.Monday is not the right choice for some cultures. DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek will give you the DayOfWeek enum value that is culture dependent. Lars, try using CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay instead of FirstFourDayWeek, that gave me the results I was looking for..." source: http://www.geekpedia.com/code72_Get-the-week-number-of-a-given-date.html  -- Thus I ask you, why do you suggest me using FirstFourDayWeek rule and not FirstDay ?

Comment: No, sorry if that was unclear, I suggest you use the property that has the correct value for the current culture, which is DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CalendarWeekRule, see example code in answer. It should contain FirstDay for your culture settings, but FirstFourDayWeek for my (dutch) culture settings.

Comment: Thats confusing again... FirstDay for my culture -- First4DayWeek for your culture? Thats looks like I have to do something like this? pseudocode: if(currentCulture("en-EN") choose FirstDay ; if(currentCulture("nl-NL") choose First4DayWeek; Is that what you mean? But I do not want to make 30 if else etc for the culture, is there not a generic way?

Comment: That's why there's DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CalendarWeekRule it does it for you, just like DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek gives you the first day of the week for the current culture. See the code in the answer above...

Comment: The solution you got for the extenstion method sample thats nice :) I will use your code and must test it properly to understand it completely...

Answer (score 1):

```
var week = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1).AddDays(7 * i);
Console.Out.WriteLine("week = {0}", week);
```

Where `i` is the number of the week you want. Since it is a DateTime type you can do whatever you want with it by locale. It would take just a little bit of work of handling leap years. You could use `DateTime.IsLeapYear()` to detect if it is a leap year, and add an addition day if the date is past 2/29.

Comment: Why is your sample code so different to mine? see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IList<int> GetWeekNumbers(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    var result = new List<int>();

    for (DateTime tm = startDate; tm <= endDate; tm = tm.AddDays(7))
    {
      result.Add(currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(tm, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, 
                                              dfi.FirstDayOfWeek));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This example will only give one week number when you switch years within 7 days.

Comment: I think the issue is that as @Jani points out .NET doesn't give the correct ISO 8601 year, not that this doesn't give two week numbers for one week.

Answer (score 1):

The [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is not ISO 8601 compatible (see Community Comment).

The free [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=168662) includes the class *Week*, which is ISO 8601 compatible:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public int GetWeekOfYear( DateTime moment )
{
  return new Week( moment ).WeekOfYear;
} // GetWeekOfYear
```